# Why is bounds checking changing the behavior of my program?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a thermal hydraulics code written in Fortran that I work on.  For my debug version, I use the `-check bounds` option in ifort 11.1 during compile time.  I have caught array bounds errors in the past in this way.  Recently, though, I was seeing that the solution was quickly blowing up for a given case.  The peculiar thing was that it was converging nicely for the release version of the code.  Sure enough, removing the `-check bounds` flag from my debug makefile cleared up the problem.

The strange thing is that the debug version was working fine for many other test cases I used before and it wasn't throwing up any errors on going outside of any array bounds in my code.  This behavior seems very strange to me and I have no idea if there is some kind of bug in my code or what.  Anybody have any ideas what could be causing this sort of behavior?

As requested, the flags I use for release and debug are:

Release: `-c -r8 -traceback -extend-source -override-limits -zero -unroll -O3`

Debug: `-c -r8 -traceback -extend-source -override-limits -zero -g -O0`

Of course, as my original question indicates, I toggle the `-check bounds` flag on and off for the debug case.

Comment: We also have no idea if there's a bug in your code since you don't show any of it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but considering it's tens of thousands of lines long, it's not really feasible for me to do so.  I also doubt it would be of any use.  I'm just wondering if somebody out there may have encountered a problem similar to this before.  Perhaps they could point me in a better direction because I'm really in the dark as to what could be causing this behavior which, to me, seems very strange.

Comment: Don't you get any detailed information about where in the code the out-of-bounds occurs?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no out-of-bounds error.  That's the strange part.  It seems to actually be changing the behavior of the numerical solution.  For an out of bounds error, standard output will specifically say something like 'index i of array is out of bounds'.  But in this case, the code is stopping because some solution parameters have become physically unrealistic due to the numerical solution diverging.  For other models, the solution performs without problem, even with check bounds enabled.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Fortran, let alone the compiler you happen to be using, but changing compiler switches like this can subtly change the layout of variables in particular on the stack so that e.g. variables that are not explicitly initialized now get different values because their position shifted from where one previous variable used to be to some new place.

Comment: Finite-precision floating point arithmetic doesn't follow the axioms of real numbers.  Changing compiler options can change the order of operations and therefore the results.  The answer changing significantly suggests that your algorithm might not be robust enough.  You might want to add debug output and see where the two "versions" diverge and see if you can improve the algorithm.  The cheap fix is to increase the precision of the variables: single to double, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if that would cause me problems in other ways.  So the solution would be to hunt down variables that are being used without being initialized?  However, I also use the `-zero` compiler option during my build, which is supposed to initialize all uninitialized or unsaved variables to zero.  So I would think the simulations should be the same in that respect whether check bounds is on or off.

Comment: Thanks M.S.B.  Actually, I'm already using double precision.  How would I compare the steps taken by the code for `check bounds` on vs. `check bounds` off?  Just open up two instances of my debugger and step through the different codes until I find where the difference is?

Comment: I don't have the help for 11.1 installed any more, but the description of -zero in the comments is inaccurate per the 13.1 docs - it doesn't cover unsaved locals (which is typically the majority of local variables).  Code that relies on -zero or -save is buggy in my opinion - they are work arounds for old, non-standard and non-portable code, not for code under active maintenance.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, IanH.  Actually, this code is in transition from old, non-standard and non-portable, to active maintenance, so this will probably be something for me to delve further into.

Comment: This sounds really interesting.  Do you think you could add the compiler options for your debug and release versions to your question?

Comment: There are some know problems with some of the ifort 11 versions.  In some cases building with the -g flag (turning on debug symbols) has caused program behavior to change.  I haven't heard of ifort 12.x or 13.x (or 9.x or 10.x) exhibiting the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect your numerical algorithm here more than the Fortran code.  Have you ensured that all of convergence and stability criteria have been met?

What it sounds like is that round-off error is causing the solution to fail to converge.  If you are on the edges of safe convergence, compiler optimizations can definitely tip things one way or another.

I use `gfortran` more than `ifort`, so I don't know all the specifics of the -unroll option, but unrolling loops can change some rounding even though the calculations seem like they *should* remain the same.  Also, debug will definitely change the exact order of memory and register access.  If the number is in the processor in some internal representation, then is written to memory and read back again, the value can change.  This can be alleviated to some extent by careful selection of `kind`.  By it's nature, this will be processor specific rather than portable.

In theory, full compliance with IEEE 754 would make floating point operations reproducible, but this is not always the case.  If debug is actually causing these problems as opposed to some other bug in your code, then other mysterious things related to the inner workings of the processor could also cause it to blow up.

I would add write statements at various key points in the code to output your data matrices (or whatever data structures you are using).  Be sure to use binary output.  Open with `form='unformatted'` and `access='direct'`.

Comment: I would suggest `access="stream"` now.